# Get content from shortcodes in PHP

Tags: php, regex

How can I get content MY_TEXT from shortcodes in PHP? I have a lot of shortcodes so i want to remove all, and get clean text. Content is from Wordpress but I build own external script, so i don't have to WP functions.

This is my example:

```
[et_pb_text admin_label="text" _builder_version="3.0.106" custom_margin="|||" custom_padding="||0px|"]
MY_TEXT
[/et_pb_text]
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use a regular expression to match the content within the tags:
`@\[([^ /]+).+\](.+)\[/\1\]@gms`

```
$re = '@\[([^ /]+).+\](.+)\[/\1\]@ms';
$str = '[et_pb_text admin_label="text" _builder_version="3.0.106" custom_margin="|||" custom_padding="||0px|"]
MY_TEXT
[/et_pb_text]';

preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER, 0);

// Print the entire match result
var_dump($matches);
```

https://regex101.com/r/FIzTuu/1

Comment: Ok but it works only for one level shortcode. When I have more shordcodes it's not working. https://regex101.com/r/FIzTuu/2